# php file path/file extension not saving to database in sql

Tags: php, sql, image, filepath

I'm successfully scrambling and uploading images to my database however the file path isn't saving to the 'profile' tab in my sql database. What's wrong here? How do i fix it.

```
include 'core/init.php';

function change_profile_image($user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn) {
$file_path = 'profile/' . substr (md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_extn;
move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `profile` = " . $file_path . "' WHERE `user_id` = " . (int)$user_id);

}

 if (isset($_FILES['profile']) === true) {
    if (empty($_FILES['profile']['name']) === true) {
       echo 'y u no choose file!';
  } else {
       $allowed = array ('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');

       $file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
       $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode ('.', $file_name)));
       $file_temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];

       if (in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true) {
        change_profile_image($session_user_id, $file_temp, $file_extn);

        header('Location: dontdelete.php');
        exit();

       }else {
        echo 'y u no jpg or png or gif';       

       }
  }
 }

if (empty($user_data['profile']) === false) {
    echo '<img src"', $user_data['profile'], '" alt="">'; 
}


?>
```

Comment: Why do you pick just the first 10 characters of the md5 hash (40 bits of data instead of 128)? Why do you use md5 at all? And what happens if two uploads are done at the same second?

Comment: I'm not sure I just thought 10 characters was prettier to look at.

Comment: Yeah, but nobody is going to look at the filename anyway, and it increases the likelihood of name collisions. I would just use the user id as the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line of code:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `profile` = " . $file_path . "' WHERE `user_id` = " . (int)$user_id);
```

Look at

```
`profile` = " . $file_path . "'
```

You forgot a ' at the beginning of `$file_path` ;)

Comment: God dam you php. I hope this fixes it. I'll give it a swirl right now!

Comment: hmmm doesn't seem to be the problem. I changed " . $file_path . "' to '" . $file_path . "'

Comment: @KiaDull Hm that's weird, can you put a `var_dump(mysql_error());` after it?

Comment: what i got
bool(true) 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Comment: I fixed the header problem... still doesn't fix the file path

Comment: @KiaDull You got bool(true)? Are you sure you var_dump()'d mysql_error() and not mysql_query? (Sorry, that was wat I first wrote but edited it)

Comment: this is what i get when i upload stuff string(0) ""

Comment: @KiaDull That means the query just works fine. Are you sure that $user_id exists in the database?